# Rails params from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, parsing

i'm trying to parse an url. For example i have this link:

localhost:3000/keys?size=3&color=blue

I know there is so Utils.parse_nested_query but I don't find this .

For example I have this link "localhost:300/employee?email=ex@d.de&user_name=faye

"localhost:3000/users.json?id=44, this is for android client

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: For example I have this link "localhost:300/employee?email=ex@d.de&user_name=faye

Comment: For example "localhost:3000/users.json?id=44, this is for android client

Comment: edit the question, don't expect people to check the comments

Comment: it says share edit flag on the bottom of the question, click edit

Answer (score 0):

params["size"] and params["color"] on your controller

Comment: but isn't ever color and size, sometimes id, sometimes color and sometimes all

Comment: but is it always the same or you have random params? you can't have random params... if you have random params you must run the params array in your controller and deal with the random data like: 

i = 0 

params[i] - do x 
i += 1